# Core Data sort descriptors based on whether a relationship exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a `Wishlist` entity, and an `Item` entity. They have bilateral to-many optional relationship, i.e. an item can be in 0 or more wishlists, and an wishlist can contain 0 or more items.

If I do `wishlist.items`, I get all the items in a certain wishlist. Now, I'd like do a fetch request and sort all my wishlists not by alphabetical order of wishlist name (like it's doing now), but by whether or not those wishlists have items.

It should sort `Wishlist`s using 2 priorities:

1 - sort by whether or not a wishlist has items or not (place those who don't at the top)

2 - sort by name if tied (if both do/don't have items)

So if I have 3 wishlists, one with 2 items named 'apple', other with no items named 'test', and the other with 3 items named 'android', it should sort them as follows, from top to bottom:

```
 1. test
 2. android
 3. apple
```

How would I achieve this using sort descriptors? My predicate is `nil`, because I'm fetching all the wishlists in Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be something like this:

Get two sets of wishlists (one with items & one without)

```
NSPredicate *withoutItems = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items.@count == 0"];
NSPredicate *withItems    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items.@count != 0"];
```

where each one should have the same sort descriptor in the fetch request:

```
NSSortDescriptor *byName  = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

now once you execute the requests, you should have two (sorted) arrays:

```
// Provided that you have a managedObjectContext
// and your fetch requests set up 
NSArray *emptyLists    = [moc executeFetchRequest:requestForEmpty error:&error];
NSArray *nonEmptyLists = [moc executeFetchRequest:requestForNonEmpty error:&error];
```

finally you could combine them if you need a unified datasource of some kind:

```
NSArray *allSorted = [emptyLists arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:nonEmptyLists];
```

Comment: This seems good, but how do I get the `allSorted` array into my `fetchedResultsController` so it can update the `tableView`? It only takes a fetch request as initialization.

Comment: Hmm sorry didn't know that you use a `fetchedResultsController`. Working on a new idea already though...

Comment: I use it because it's much easier to update my table this way, I just set the fetch request I want and it automatically updates the `tableView`. Looking forward to see what you can come up with!

Comment: OK I've tried a few things but I'm afraid in your case the best option would be to ditch the `fetchedResultsController`. Having said that, if someone would come up with a decent solution I would be really glad to know about it as well. I'm going to leave the answer active though since the solution would work on a non-fetchedResultsController scenario.

Comment: I can't ditch it, sorry. It's essential to my design.